# Chicken and egg dilemma with linked list implementation

Tags: java, c++, standards

I mainly learned about linked lists in the context of C++. Here's a node implementation

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  node* next;//node IS what is being defined
};
```

I was taught that the C++ standards make a special exception for this because there is a self reference where the struct being defined has a member that is itself and that's a problem because it's not fully defined. Why is this possible? This screwed me up on an interview question and I need to know if other languages support this. For example I've seen a Java implementation

```
class Link {
public int data1;
public double data2;
public Link nextLink;

//Link constructor
public Link(int d1, double d2) {
    data1 = d1;
    data2 = d2;
}

//Print Link data
public void printLink() {
    System.out.print("{" + data1 + ", " + data2 + "} ");
}
```

}

So this seems to support Java makes some sort of "special exception" as well where `public Link nextLink;` occurs within the implementation of `Link`. In general do most programing languages have this feature? When can it be used?

So you are always allowed to have:

```
struct X{
 X* y;
};
```

and 
    Plublic class X
    {
      Public X y;
    }

Comment: There is no dilemma here, nor a special case; `next` is a reference/pointer.

Comment: I think you were taught wrong.  There is no "special exception" here.  A class in C++ can have a pointer to any class at all as the type of one of its fields, not just itself.  Similarly, a class in Java can have any class at all as the type of one of its fields.  What  you can't have in C++ is a class where the type one of the fields is the same class, that is, not a pointer.

Comment: Well, there is sort of a special exception here as the structure is being used before it's fully defined; this is however well supported in many modern programming languages (maybe even most?) and therefore not so special any more.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't this be possible? The field of type `Link` is just a reference, this is no special exception.

In your case, the reference is to an object of same type as the one being defined, but **there is no recursion in memory**, since the reference is just a pointer. Thus, no technical problem.

You could also say that within the class declaration, the class is not fully defined, yet you use the referenced object's methods and field. But this is exactly the same thing as using methods and fields of `this` within the class declaration, or even using methods before their own declaration. **The compiler deals with it all the time**, no worries.

*Side note: by the way, the chicken egg came before the chicken, from a bird that was not exactly a chicken.*

Comment: That depends on whether you define "chicken egg" as "egg containing a chicken" or "egg laid by a chicken".  Since many eggs contain no birds (or reptiles, fish, whatever), I'd have to favour the latter definition, which makes your side note wrong. :-)

Comment: +1 for the insight :) Well, I was favoring the other definition here. With either definition, the answer is obvious. With your definition, the answer is "the chicken".

Answer (score 1):

There is no real dilemma here. The `next` is just a pointer to another "object" of struct. Similarly, `Link` is just a reference to another object of the same definition.

Since a class is just a definition of what is contained within an object of its type and since there can be many objects, for each class definitions, there can be a reference to an object of the class within the object of another.

Answer (score 1):

`next` is a *pointer* (4 or 8 bytes in size depending on whether you are on a 32 vs 64 bit system) which holds an address to a location in memory containing an instance of the `struct node`.  By the time the `struct node` is compiled, the compiler knows the size of the type and how to lay it out in memory.  At run-time, the 4 or 8-byte *pointer* will be assigned a value which points to any instance of `struct node`.  It could be any instance of this type.  In other words, the pointer is a variable used at runtime.  It is not a sort of type definition in-and-of-itself which would lead to a recursive type definition as you describe.